# Eleminate source map generation in prime faces extension

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces-extensions

How to eliminate source map generation in PrimeFaces Extension.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/primefaces-extensions/core/master/src/sourcemap/4.0.0/primefaces-extensions.js.map

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/primefaces-extensions/core/master/src/sourcemap/4.0.0/tooltip.js.map

Is there anyway to generate internal URL instead of external URL ?

Comment: did you find a way?

Comment: Removed one of the jar file which was optional for my project requirement. Do not remember name of the jar file.